# JAVA - Copy an Image, Modify specific Pixels of it and save it as temporary .png file

Tags: java, graphics, pixel

I have got a 64 x 64 pixels png-texturemap and i need to copy a part of it and paste it a few pixels underneeth its original position because i have a slightly modified 3dmodel which's texturemap does not completely fit the original one. But the code i wrote errors and i can not make out where the problem is located.

This is what i have so far:

```
public ResourceLocation getTemporaryTexturefile(AbstractClientPlayer player) {
        try {
            BufferedImage texture = ImageIO.read(Minecraft.getMinecraft().getResourceManager()
                    .getResource(player.getLocationSkin()).getInputStream());
            if (texture != null) {
                byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) texture.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
                // copying the armtexture (sides)
                ArrayList<Byte> armtexture_bottom = new ArrayList<Byte>();
                ArrayList<Byte> armtexture_side = new ArrayList<Byte>();

                for (int pixelY = 0; pixelY < 4; pixelY++) {
                    // x locatet at 16 until 19 and y 48 to 52
                    for (int pixelX = 0; pixelX < 4; pixelX++) {
                        int posPixel = (16 * 64 + (pixelY * 64)) + 48 + pixelX;
                        armtexture_bottom.add(pixels[posPixel]);
                    }

                }

                for (int pixelY = 0; pixelY < 11; pixelY++) {
                    // 20 - 31 (x) & 40 - 56 (x)
                    for (int pixelX = 0; pixelX < 16; pixelX++) {
                        int posPixel = (pixelY * 64 + (40 + pixelX));
                        armtexture_side.add(pixels[posPixel]);
                    }

                }
                int counterY = 0;
                int counterX = 0;
                // pasting the two bytearrays onto the new image.
                for (int pixelY = 0; pixelY < 64; pixelY++) {
                    counterY++;
                    if (pixelY >= 24 && pixelY < 45) {
                        for (int pixelX = 0; pixelX < 64; pixelX++) {
                            if (pixelX > 39 && pixelY > 31) {
                                counterX++;
                                if (pixelY > 43) {
                                    int posinbytearray = (pixelY * 64 + pixelX) % 128;
                                    int rowYInByteArray = counterY - 43;
                                    pixels[pixelY * 64 + pixelX] = armtexture_side
                                            .get(posinbytearray - (16 * rowYInByteArray));
                                }
                            }
                            // pasting the top&bottom arm texture toimage array
                            if (pixelX > 47 && pixelX <= 51) {
                                int posinbytearray = ((pixelY * 64 + pixelX) % 16);
                                int rowYInByteArray = counterY - 23;
                                System.out.println(rowYInByteArray);
                                if((4 * rowYInByteArray + pixelX % 4)<=15){
                                pixels[pixelY * 64 + pixelX] = armtexture_bottom.get((4 * rowYInByteArray + pixelX % 4));
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("Bigger than 15!!!!!");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                InputStream newTextureBytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(pixels);
                BufferedImage newTexture = ImageIO.read(newTextureBytes);
                if (!new File(Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getPath() + "RLM/playerskin.png").exists()) {
                    System.out.println(Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getPath().toString());
                    ImageIO.write(newTexture, "png",new File(Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getPath() + "/RLM/playerskin.png"));
                }
                return new ResourceLocation("reallifemod:RLM/playerskin.png");
            }
        } catch (

        IOException e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

But my problem is, that this Codepart errors and the 4*rowYInByteArray+pixelX%4 is bigger than 15 - the bytearray of the copied part is 16 by 16 pixels of size:

```
    pixels[pixelY * 64 + pixelX] = armtexture_bottom.get((4 * rowYInByteArray + pixelX % 4));
}else{
    System.out.println("Bigger than 15!!!!!");
```

And another error - this line errors with image==null exception:

```
ImageIO.write(newTexture, "png",new File(Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir.getPath() + "/RLM/playerskin.png"));
```

Comment: Please provide your snippet code that you have been tried so far...

Comment: At the moment i only have a bunc of pixels in a byte array like this: byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

Comment: We want to help you but you will need to post as much code as possible for us to understand the 'story' behind your code.

Comment: Okay - now i have added the code i have so far. Hope somebody knows how to solve that error.